# After Upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04 build-essential, g++, gcc & cpp held broken packages

Tags: package-management, 18.04

After Upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04 from 16.04 build-essential, g++, gcc & cpp `E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 build-essential : Depends: gcc (>= 4:7.2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: g++ (>= 4:7.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


$ sudo apt-get install gcc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc : Depends: gcc-7 (>= 7.3.0-12~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The same type of output for g++ & cpp

How to fix this?

Comment: I'm getting this same error now (2018/12/10), even though I've removed all 3rd party PPAs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've encountered the same - on Ubuntu 16.04 I had the [Toolchain Test Builds PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test) for gcc and clang builds, including `gcc-7`. During the upgrade to 18.04, 3rd party repositories were disabled by the installation process, with this PPA included.

To fix this, try (re?)adding the toolchain PPA to your apt sources list:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
```

Then, when installing `build-essential`, it should successfully pick `gcc-7` from the toolchain PPA.

Comment: This didn't work for me, it still says gcc-7 cannot be found.

Comment: this doesn't work for me either, same error as void.pointer

Comment: Does not work for me either. I upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, but apparently I had used a different PPA when I installed those tools.

For me I fixed it with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/gcc
```

Comment: This did not solve the problem. The problem persists

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue while upgrading from `14.04 LTS` to `16.04 LTS`. I have written the detailed solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1274779/840045). But for the sake of convenience I will reproduce the key points here.

Remove all dependent libraries (`autoremove`) and install all missing libraries using `sudo apt-get -f install` (`-f` means `--fix-missing`)

```bsh
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Install `ubuntu toolchain` from PPA

```bsh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
```

Install `aptitude`.

```bsh
sudo apt install aptitude
```

Recursively try installing the broken libraries until you solve the conflict by upgrading or fixing a specific library. In my case I had to fix `libstdc++6`

```bsh
$ sudo aptitude -f install build-essential
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  build-essential cpp{a} cpp-5{a} g++{a} g++-5{a} gcc{a} gcc-5{a} libasan2{a} libcc1-0{ab} 
  libcilkrts5{a} libgcc-5-dev{a} liblsan0{ab} libmpx0{a} libstdc++-5-dev{a} 
The following packages will be upgraded:
  gcc-5-base libstdc++6{b} 
2 packages upgraded, 14 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 29.6 MB of archives. After unpacking 100 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 liblsan0 : Depends: gcc-9-base (= 9.3.0-10ubuntu2~16.04) but 9.3.0-11ubuntu0~14.04 is installed.
 libcc1-0 : Depends: gcc-9-base (= 9.3.0-10ubuntu2~16.04) but 9.3.0-11ubuntu0~14.04 is installed.
 libstdc++6 : Depends: gcc-9-base (= 9.3.0-10ubuntu2~16.04) but 9.3.0-11ubuntu0~14.04 is installed.
```

As `build-essential` needs `gcc-5`.

```bsh
$ sudo apt-get -f install gcc-5

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc-5 : Depends: cpp-5 (= 5.5.0-12ubuntu1~16.04) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.5.0-12ubuntu1~16.04) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12 is to be installed
         Depends: libcc1-0 (>= 5.5.0-12ubuntu1~16.04) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: libgcc-5-dev (= 5.5.0-12ubuntu1~16.04) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

But `gcc-5` in turn depends on `cpp-5`

```bsh
$ sudo apt-get -f install cpp-5

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cpp-5 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.5.0-12ubuntu1~16.04) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12 is to be installed
```

`cpp-5` depends on `gcc-5-base`. Here you can see there is a specific conflict. Aptitide gives multiple choices to solve the conflict. In my case upgrading the `libstdc++6` solvd the problem.

```bsh
$sudo aptitude -f install gcc-5-base
The following packages will be REMOVED:  
  gcc-5-base{u} 
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 67.6 kB will be freed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libstdc++6 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) but it is not going to be installed.
open: 115; closed: 488; defer: 35; conflict: 58                                                          .The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:                        
1)     gcc-5-base [5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12 (now, xenial-security, xenial-updates)]

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Upgrade the following packages:                                                                     
1)      libstdc++6 [5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12 (now, xenial-security, xenial-updates) -> 9.3.0-10ubuntu2~16.0
```

Finally, now the conlict is resolved try installing `build-essentials` again.

```bsh
$ sudo aptitude -f install build-essential
```